# Check for matchings in R

Tags: r, matching

I have a table with two columns:

```
aaa     bbb
a1      b2
a1      b6
a1      b2
a1      b2
a1      b5
a1      b6
a2      b2
a2      b2
a2      b2
a2      b6
a2      b6
a2      b5
```

Neither of these columns should be considered as sorted. What I am trying to do is find the most elegant way to count how many combination of aaa,bbb given aaa exist, then take the most popular combination (100 say) and subtract the sum of all the remaining combinations (10 say) which is expected to be less than the popular one. The output should be the element aaa and the difference between these two numbers. For example, the output of the above should be as follows:

```
var     cnt
a1      0
a2      0
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to consider how you want to break ties. The following solution doesn't deal with this issue, i.e. assumes there are no ties.

```
library(plyr)
#use ddply to split-apply-combine according to aaa values
ddply(DF, .(aaa), function(d) {
  #sort bbb and calculate run lengths
  nums <- rle(sort(as.character(d$bbb)))
  #maximum run length
  mnum <- max(nums$lengths) 
  #the desired difference
  mnum - sum(nums$lengths[nums$lengths!=mnum])
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! One last thing; I am trying to expand the above a little bit. In fact, I want to compute a vector - with length the same as the number of rows in table B - the values of which should be computed by dividing the value cnt of table B with the number of total observations of the same var in table A. In the above scenario, I should get c(0/6, 0/6) which is equal to c(0,0). I have implemented that already but it takes a lot of time to finish as it is based upon for-loops. Any idea on how to do that same yet without for-loops?

Comment: Divide the last line in my answer by `nrow(d)`?

Comment: sorry, that's a silly question but what's d? I didn't define but the function ran anyway! what;s the right way to ran the above function?

Comment: `ddply` splits the data.frame according to the splitting variable and passes the results of the splitting to the anonymous function. This function has a parameter (I called it `d`) that takes a data.frame. You may want to read [this paper](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v40/i01/paper).

Comment: so, does parameter d represent the data.frame DF? I am impressed from the fact that R does not complain about the fact that d is not defined... I do that `fnl <- ddply(df, .(aaa), function(d) {...}` in order to use the generated data later on, but still not clear whether this is the correct... can you please help me to understand why R does not complain at all?

Comment: `d` is defined. It's a function parameter. And `ddply` passes the "chunks" (from splitting it) of the data.frame to it. I don't know how to explain that better.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way using `data.table`

```
require(data.table)
DT <- data.table(df) # where df is your data.frame
setkey(DT[, .N, by=list(aaa, bbb)], aaa, N)[, list(cnt = 
                                      N[.N]-sum(N[-.N])), by=aaa]

   aaa cnt
1:  a1   0
2:  a2   0
```

---

The idea is to first get the count for each combination. This is accomplished by:

```
OUT <- DT[, .N, by = list(aaa, bbb)]
# which gives you: 
   aaa bbb N
1:  a1  b2 3
2:  a1  b6 2
3:  a1  b5 1
4:  a2  b2 3
5:  a2  b6 2
6:  a2  b5 1
```

After this, we `setkey` on columns *aaa* and *N*, which'll sort them by default (that's the only purpose of setting the key here).

```
OUT <- setkey(DT[, .N, by=list(aaa, bbb)], aaa, N)
# which gives you:
  aaa bbb N
1:  a1  b5 1
2:  a1  b6 2
3:  a1  b2 3
4:  a2  b5 1
5:  a2  b6 2
6:  a2  b2 3
```

Now that it's sorted, we can split/group by column *aaa* and get the final *cnt* column. Since *N* is sorted, the maximum value will always be the last. So, we take the last value `N[.N]` and subtract it with the sum of remaining values `N[-.N]` while grouping by column *aaa*. This is what the last part:

```
OUT[, list(cnt = N[.N]-sum(N[-.N])), by=aaa]
```

accomplishes. You can chain all these commands together (as I've done) or you can split them into separate steps (as I've shown for explanation). It's your choice.

**Note:** This'll result in a negative value if the same maximum occurs for more than 1 combination of *aaa, bbb*.